# What is provisioning in Wireless technology

Tags: wireless

While reading about wireless technology, I usually meet the term "provisioning".
Anyone can help me to define what is "provisioning" exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Provisioning" means doing whatever is necessary to provide a particular service. It can include purchasing equipment, installing equipment, delivering equipment to customers, configuring equipment to provide specific services, and so on.